# How to insert image after div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello how can I set image after div with image that will suit to browser width. I have this 
code but it doesn't work properly. I want to image looks like in this [way](http://oi58.tinypic.com/rszltl.jpg) I mean how to make this line between images.

```
.phone{
    margin:0 auto;
    background: url(images/umow1.png);
    width:74px;
    height:74px;
}
.phone:after{
    content: url(images/kreska2.png);
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    max-width:300px;
    width:100%;
    left: 72px;
}
.message{
    margin:0 auto;
    background: url(images/napisz1.png);
    width:74px;
    height:74px;
}
.location{
    margin:0 auto;
    background: url(images/odwiedz1.png);
    width:74px;
    height:74px;
}
```

Comment: please create a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ including your markup

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5971/ I want to connect icons with this green line

Comment: maybe this http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-process-steps does what you want?

Comment: So, do you want the green line to stop at the phone or just pass through it through the whole window? If you want to stop it at the phone you can just remove `left: 72px;` from phone:after

Comment: I pasted link in first post how should it looks. This line can appears more times just want to connect this icons with this line. @nozzleman Something like this But need this icon and this green line :)

Comment: Your explanation is very hard to understand. just some steps: your images are not aligned a side because they are inside block elements, the columns. If you for example add a ```display: inline-block``` to the cols, you come a bit nearer to your example with the lines. http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5971/

Comment: There is what I need http://oi59.tinypic.com/o5svbn.jpg Icons must be links.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of z-index so you can overlap the line with your circles.
Here's my sample code, this would make it easier for you to understand the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/C2yW4/

CSS

```
#linear,
#circle-group {
    position: absolute; /*we need a position so we can use z-index.*/
}
#linear {
    top: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 0; /*It means the layer is at the most bottom*/
}
#circle-group {
    z-index: 1; /*This layer will be displayed upfront than the lower value*/
}
.circle {
    background: #65CA22;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="linear">
        <hr />
     </div>
     <div id="circle-group">
         <div class="circle"></div>
         <div class="circle"></div>
         <div class="circle"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to apply absolute/fixed/relative position so z-index would work.

Comment: What If my icons are transparent? Line go throw them.

Comment: Well that is an another case, if your icons are transparent then it is surely your line would be seen, unless you convert it to opaque(not transparent) and instead of a transparent background convert it to a color that would match the background, so it would still look like a transparent.
That is all I can think as an alternative right now.

Comment: I can't do it in this way because icons are on image.

Comment: Try converting your png to jpeg, so that the line wouldn't pass through your image.